# How to create a new object of type 'T' in generic class in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, typescript-generics

I have the following service

```
@Injectable()
export class CollectionService<T> {    

    constructor(protected http: Http) {}

    factory<T>(item?: any): T {
        let type: new (item?: any) => T;
        return new type(item);
    }

    item(id): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
            .map((resp: Response)=> this.factory(resp.json()))
            .catch((error: any) => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Compilation passes successfully, but i have folowing error in browser console

```
TypeError: type is not a constructor
at PortalVideoService.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/services/collection/collection.service.ts.CollectionService.factory (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1568:16)
at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1580:64
at Array.map (native)
at MapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1580:29)
at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24034:35)
at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:13455:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:101703:38)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2838:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:93420:37)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2837:36)
```

How can I create an object of type T?

Answer (score 8):

The name `T` only exists at compile time. You can use it for type checking but you cannot construct an object of type T unless you have access to the constructor.

Change the definition of `factory` to take the runtime type constructor as an argument:

```
factory<T>(type: {new(): T}, item?: any): T {
    return new type(item);
}
```

Now the only problem will be working out where you get the type argument; you probably also need to pass it into the `item()` method so that the compiler knows what type to make the `Observable<T>`.

Comment: I tried to pass a type through the class constructor. `constructor(protected http: Http, private type: {new(item: any): T})`. It is ugly but worked fine. But when I did `ng build -prod` i get `ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 14:53 in the original .ts file)`

Comment: Googling that error seems to indicate that it is a problem in your angular templates. https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5 (section 4)

Answer (score 1):

You may pass the constructor as a class generic, instead of method.

```
export class CollectionService<T, CT extends { new(item?: any): T }> {    

    constructor(protected http: Http, private type: CT) {}

    factory(item?: any): T {
        return new this.type(item);
    }

    // ...
}

class CustomClass {
    constructor(private item?: any) {
    }
 };


let cs = new CollectionService<CustomClass, { new(): CustomClass }>(http, CustomClass);
console.dir(cs.factory(123));

// UPDATE
class CustomClassService extends CollectionService<CustomClass, { new(): CustomClass }> {
    constructor(protected http: Http) {
        super(http, CustomClass);
    }
}

let ccs = new CustomClassService(http);
console.dir(ccs.factory(456));
```

Comment: `ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve type CT (position 14:52 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol CollectionService` when `ng build -prod`

Comment: Are you trying the [The generic type parameter is not supported in Angular?](https://github.com/rangle/angular-2-aot-sandbox#service-with-generic-type-param-top)

Comment: but there is no generic type parameters. isn't it?

Comment: I think so... Maybe a `CustomClassService`? I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do what you're doing, simply do

```
.map((resp: Response)=> resp.json())
```

and if you want a custom type for the response do

```
.map((resp: Response)=> resp.json() as CustomResponse)
```

where `CustomResponse` is an interface.

Comment: In this case I still get a simple Object instead of an object of type T. `.map((resp: Response)=> resp.json() as T)`

Comment: That works if `CustomResponse` is an interface, but not if it is a class with its own methods. For that you have to do as the OP is trying and actually create a real object from the response.

Comment: @Duncan True, although I'm still finding it difficult to see the use case for doing that?

Comment: @Duncan and how can i create a real object?

Comment: @AndreyK see the answer I posted, you have to pass the actual type around as a parameter